# Android closed test when app is already in production

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am working on a app that is already released on the play store. Is it possible to have test app without actually replacing the app that is currently in production? I noticed that there is a closed track which I have used before, but only before launch. Can I still use it after launch without replacing the app that is currently in the play store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en) said that:

> If you're testing an existing app that you've published before, only users in your test group will receive an update for your closed version.

That means you can create a closed track normally for your testers group, even your app is published